# Python: Model Building - Which Model to choose

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning-model

I am having a data frame with 4 columns and my database looks like below:

`Sl.No  Column-1            Column-2       Item code
 1    gaddhjhd,dfhhaso     dfkjdhf         3027-121
 2    fdlkdsa,fdhjudf      dfhjdiufu       3027-320
 3    dfhidfndf            eioruoier       3027-343
 4    rieruiq              jdjlasjd        3027-420
 5    lkjdfi               dfjdflajdfi     3027-720`

Now I need to build a model in python where the machine has to read `column-1 & Column-2` and create a dictionary that if in future if the keywords in `Column-1 & Column-2` comes it should display this Item-Code.

If in future if new keyword comes it should add that Item-code to the dictionary. Like this I need to create a Model. Which model I need to use... Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

No need to build a model.
Just a simple dictionary will suffice.
Suppose your csv file name is "abc.csv"
example code:

```
import csv
f = open('./abc.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

next(csv_f) #for header skip

model_dict = dict()
for row in csv_f:
    col_1 = str(row[1])
    col_2 = str(row[2])
    model_dict[(col_1,col_2)] = str(row[3])
```

And just check the pair key if it exists in dictionary or not.
If not add it.